how do you connect to mssql server using sqlalchemy library in python
I am trying to use sqladchemy library to connect to mssql server and insert some data, the data is simple csv file.
print(df)

Server IP OS
ServerABC 129.0.0.0 Mac
Server123 129.0.01  Windows10

my script is this:
import pyodbc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from slqalchemy import create_engine



engine=create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://sqlserver.com,15001/db_name?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server?trusted_connection=yes")

df.to_sql('table_name', con=engine, if_exists='append')

engine.dispose()

I get this error:
(podbc.InterffaceError) ('IM002', [Microsoft}[ODBC driver Manager] data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) backgroun on this error at https://sqlalche.me/e/20/rvf5

When I try to use the following connection string and method, it works:
con=pyodbc.connect('Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
'Server=sqlserver.com;',
'Database=db_name;'
)

query="select * from table name"
df=pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
con.close()

print(df)

Is there anything I need to do with sqlalchemy library to make this work? Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Try mssql+pyodbc://@sqlserver.com:15001/…
